# Rails 5 javascript for Ajax controlled partial is acting strangely & it can't initialize bootstrap-star-rating inputs as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using [this js library  (bootstrap-stars-rating)](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-star-rating) to provide star ratings using jquery in my Rails 5 application

It works well except that if I am calling it inside a partial that is renerdered by Ajax helper, it will not initialize the javascript code necessary to render the stars

I tried to solve this by making a globally accessible function in my webpacker init file for that library like this:

```
import "bootstrap-star-rating";
import "bootstrap-star-rating/css/star-rating.css";
import "bootstrap-star-rating/js/star-rating.js";
import "bootstrap-star-rating/themes/krajee-fas/theme.min.css";

const rating_options = {
  size: 'xs',
  showCaption: false,
  step: 0.5,
  filledStar: '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>',
  emptyStar: '<i class="far fa-star"></i>',
  theme: 'krajee-fas',
  hoverOnClear: false
}
// initialize the star rating across the application
const initStarRating = () => {
  document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", () => {
    console.log('hey I was run');
    $(".bootstrap-rating").rating(rating_options);
  }, {passive: true});
}

// initialize specific star rating in a specific form for ajax 
const initStarRatingForObj = (obj) => {
  {
    console.log(obj)
    console.log(obj.find(".bootstrap-rating"))
    obj.find(".bootstrap-rating").rating(rating_options);
  }
}

// binding the function so I can access it globally
window.initStarRatingForObj = initStarRatingForObj

export { initStarRating }
```

The problem is that if I call this function above in the js.erb file that renders the partial, passing the correct object to the function `initStarRatingForObj`, it will break & give error that ***it can't find the `rating()`*** function ((that one called in the initStarRating))

This is very weird as the `rating()` function is already available & working in that file, so how does it work in `initStarRating()` but not in the `initStarRatingForObj()` ?

I have been looking into this for hours but it doesn't work, I hope someone can point out what the issue is.

Note:
The same partial is working well in the same page ***if it is not rendered*** by Ajax response